# Is it possible to build an HTML5 mobile app that requires large storage?

Tags: android, ios, html, local-storage

I am aware that you can build a simple mobile app that doesn't require large local storage by using HTML5 local storage. However I'm wondering if it's also possible to build something that requires large storage: for example if your app needs to store lots of huge images.

I'm asking because HTML5 local storage is known to be limited to certain size on most browsers. I am not sure if this is the case even if you package it into an app.

Comment: do you wish to package these large images with your application? or is this data something that will be downloaded during use of the application?

Comment: It will be downloaded during the use of the application, which means it will continue to increase with usage. Basically it's an app that provides interface to contents which will be stored on the device.